# Can I run SVN update and commit without using sudo?

Tags: permissions, svn

Under my local development environment (Ubuntu) I have a checked out SVN repository.

The files have the owner myuser:myuser.

However, I must use sudo for the "svn up" and "svn ci" commands. Also in doing this, if a new file is created during "sudo svn up", then that file is given default ownership of root:root, which I don't want.

Is it possible to run those SVN commands under my default user account, instead of sudo?

Comment: why must use sudo? is there any error message given if you don't?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you done the checkout using sudo? Maybe there are still some files with permissions root:root. Just do a `chown -R myuser:mygroup <directory>` on the repository directory again. Then try again to update.

Maybe you can also post your error message when doing SVN operations without sudo.

Comment: Thanks. I did the chown (not chmod that you indicated, right?). I think the problem was I had never done a chown of the parent directory, only sub directories.

Comment: You're welcome. Ooops. Of course chown. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Are all files really owned by myuser, or is the `.svn` folder (which won't appear unless you do `ls -la`) owned by someone else?

Even if the .svn folder looks right, `chown -R myuser:myuser .` (note use `.` not `*`) in the checkout folder should fix it.  There are a lot of files in various subfolders of .svn that could be causing the issue.

Or there's always the obvious option... are the files owned by myuser but you're logged in as someone else? :)